# How to override the numbering scheme used for SNAPSHOT versions in Gradle's maven-publish plugin?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I'm using the `maven-publish` plugin in my Gradle build. When my project's `version` includes `-SNAPSHOT` (eg, `1.3-SNAPSHOT`), it publishes with a generated version, like `foo-1.3-20230418.171737-3.war`.

How can I customize the snapshot version suffix ("20230418.171737-3" in the sample above)? For example, I might want just the date and a simple sequential number, like `1.3-20210418-1`.

Relevant portions of my `build.gradle`:

```yaml
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'GitHubPackages'
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/myrepo")
            credentials {
                username = project.findProperty("githubpackages.user")
                password = project.findProperty("githubpackages.token")
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        webApp(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootWar
            groupId = 'com.me'
            artifactId = 'foo'
        }
    }
}
```